# Return array for box

Tags: java, arrays

working on the code below. I want return the values of the two elements as arrays.

```
public static int[]box ={20,50,60};
public static int[] getBoxDimensions(int[]box){
   int[] dimension;
   int length = box[0];
   int width = box[box.length - 1];   
   {
      dimension=[][]; 
   }     
   return dimension;
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    System.out.println(getBoxDimensions(box));
}
```

Comment: Can you use `ArrayList`?

Comment: no can't use arrayList.

Comment: what did you mean by **I need to return the dimension of the box in an array** ? i don't get you, why you don't `return box;` ?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - it's all over the place at the moment. It's not clear to me what your code is meant to be doing, either... what would you expect the return value to be in this particular case?

Comment: the return value would be the dimension of the box return in an array.

Comment: can you provide an example input output please?

Comment: public static int[]box ={20,50,60}; this is the array with the first element length,width and weight the box can contain. i need to return the dimension length and width in an array.

Comment: `int[] dim = new int[2]; dim[0] = box[0]; dim[1] = box[1], return (dim);`

Comment: thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can create an array for 2 int values like this :

```
int[] dimension = new int[2];//create an array of size 3

dimension[0] = box[0];//add in the first position length
dimension[1] = box[box.length - 1];//add in the second position width

return dimension;//return your array
```